# I can't open a dialog from GCM onMessage in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

When sending a message to my android app using google cloud messaging I can't figure out how to open a yes or no dialog (like a javasrcript confirm box) that opens a website in the browser if they hit yes or does nothing if they hit no.

I have spent too many hours and hate to show you this basic code without the failing code that should be at the end, but I am just out of ideas and have tried too many variations of samples I found online. I suspect that they failed either because I used the wrong context or because I was trying to do it from this service class.

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
@Override
protected void onMessage( Context myContext, Intent intent ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i( LOG_TAG, "GCMIntentService onMessage called" );
    Log.i( LOG_TAG, "Message is: " + intent.getStringExtra( "data" ) );
    JSONObject o = API.getJSONObj(intent.getStringExtra( "data" ));
    String URL = "";
    String message = "";
    try {
            URL = o.getString("URL");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
            message = o.getString("message");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /* Code to open dialog or website goes here */
```

Comment: Why don't you make a status bar notification instead? It would be less intrusive and it can launched from a service.

Comment: inside your application create a new activity and the activity contains only dialog box if yes open a website if no close your application. call the particular activity using intent in GCM receiver

Answer (score 9, accepted):

onMessage method called every time when you got any notification. For opening a dialog box on notification you can start an another activity in onMessage and put your code (for dialog box) in that Activity. Or you can also make it notification. Like this:

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService
{
   @Override
   protected void onMessage( Context myContext, Intent intent) 
   {
        <your code>
        //if you want to show any dialog directly.
        Intent i = new Intent(myContext,<your Activity.class>);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        i.putExtra("message", message);
        myContext.startActivity(i); 

      //if you want to show message through notification.
      NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_icon,arg1.getStringExtra("message"), when);
      String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
      Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,<Your Activity>.class);
      // set intent so it does not start a new activity  
      notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
      PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
      notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, arg1.getStringExtra("message"), intent);
      notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
      notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this working, In GCMIntentService write the above code in generate notification

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.appicon,
                message, when);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                YourClassName.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
```

when click the notification it goes to the activity in your application, after that in the activity you may create the dialog-box and whatever you want put inside your activity