# Gcm not being Recivied

Tags: android

I am working on a project that notifies an android application using push notifications using Google Cloud Messaging. I have implemented the application server in PHP. When i run the android application, the device gets the registration id from the GCM server and it sends the registration id to the PHP server(application server). But i get the following httpresponse from the server :

```
{
    "multicast_id": 7015234441922271670,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [{
        "message_id": "0:1344007383866721%2adac3a0ad8b3148"
    }]
}
```

But Messages not delivered to device. any suggestion pls.

If anyone have above problem please check below It may help you

Finally I have found solution  On the server side, as long as the application is behaving well, everything should work normally. However, if a bug in the application triggers multiple registrations for the same device, it can be hard to reconcile state and you might end up with duplicate messages.

GCM provides a facility called "canonical registration IDs" to easily recover from these situations. A canonical registration ID is defined to be the ID of the last registration requested by your application. This is the ID that the server should use when sending messages to the device.

If later on you try to send a message using a different registration ID, GCM will process the request as usual, but it will include the canonical registration ID in the registration_id field of the response. Make sure to replace the registration ID stored in your server with this canonical ID, as eventually the ID you're using will stop working.

Comment: see my answer this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017176/i-cant-open-a-dialog-from-gcm-onmessage-in-android/14017645#14017645

Comment: From [gcm guide](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) Note: "If your organization has a firewall that restricts the traffic to or from the Internet, you need to configure it to allow connectivity with GCM in order for your Android devices to receive messages. The ports to open are: 5228, 5229, and 5230. GCM typically only uses 5228, but it sometimes uses 5229 and 5230. GCM doesn't provide specific IPs, so you should allow your firewall to accept incoming connections from all IP addresses contained in the IP blocks listed in Google's ASN of 15169." Check your firewall.

Comment: Before it has worked but now It's not working how can i do above?

Comment: Disable your firewall. You mentioned that it has worked, be sure that the message is still the same and you do not receive any other number at the canonical_id, a number on  that field means that the device has more than one registration ID, you should update yor database and deliver future messages to that number.

Comment: No notifications are received on my app and I get this response for my post request:
{"multicast_id":6870303680709824663,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1354074200871681%978fee92f9fd7ecd"}]}
What can be the problem? i Checked everything It's ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone have above problem please check below It may help you

Finally I have found solution On the server side, as long as the application is behaving well, everything should work normally. However, if a bug in the application triggers multiple registrations for the same device, it can be hard to reconcile state and you might end up with duplicate messages.

GCM provides a facility called "canonical registration IDs" to easily recover from these situations. A canonical registration ID is defined to be the ID of the last registration requested by your application. This is the ID that the server should use when sending messages to the device.

If later on you try to send a message using a different registration ID, GCM will process the request as usual, but it will include the canonical registration ID in the registration_id field of the response. Make sure to replace the registration ID stored in your server with this canonical ID, as eventually the ID you're using will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you [PushNotification](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)
check Your `Androidmanifest.xml` your GCM Notification with  your packagename

```
 <uses-permission android:name="yourpackege.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="yourpackege" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: I have checked in androidManifest.xml .I have put Package name correctly but I don't know what happen