# GoogleCloudMessaging (GCM) Android client

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to make [GCM](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/google/gcm/index.html) work with my Android application. I have some questions.

1. In [this article](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/google/gcm/gs.html) in section **Step 3: Write Your Application** I can't see any Service. How can I start my `BroadcastReceiver` without a service? Should I start it? In this section there isn't any Service.
2. In section **Writing the Server Code**, in the code, there are two strings:

   USERNAME = ''

   PASSWORD = ''

   What values should I use for them?

Comment: create a package of same name as of your application package then create your service there and don't forgot to register your broadcast in manifest , you can see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017176/i-cant-open-a-dialog-from-gcm-onmessage-in-android/14017645#14017645

Comment: GCMBaseIntentService now is Deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no need for a service.  The broadcast receiver is started by Android when a GCM message arrives. In the old implementation there was an intent service that was called by the broadcast receiver, but it's not required anymore.
2. The user is `<your Google API project Id>@gcm.googleapis.com`.  The password is the API key. However,  the code sample you mentioned is for the new XMPP based API. It's simpler to use the HTTP based API which only requires the API key in the headers of the request.  The code in the section you mentioned has a link to an HTTP sample.

In the HTTP API you POST an HTTP request the looks like this to `https://android.googleapis.com` :

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyB-1uEai2WiUapxCs2Q0GZYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "registration_ids" : ["APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx..."],
  "data" : {
    ...
  },
}
```

Comment: what about some default ending? When can i find it?

Comment: @Tooto Sorry about that, I answered the question from a mobile device so it was harder to search for the exact user id. I edited the answer. Still, it is not recommended to use that code sample. You need that sample only for Cloud Connection Server, which allows your app to send messages back to your server (and requires filling a special signup form which needs to be approved by Google). If you only need to push messages from your server to your app, the HTTP solution is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

@Tooto : If you look into the article carefully then you will find in the Manifest.xml the entry of the service class.

```
 <service android:name=".MyIntentService" />
```

For more details on how to set up the GCM in your android app you can refer to this link : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/